# Calculating Finish Time of FCFS & SJF Scheduling Algorithm VB.Net System

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, scheduling

Need help for First Come First Serve (FCFS) and Shortest Job First (SJF) Algorithm System on getting finish time for both algorithms.

Language: VB.Net [System GIU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/429Jn.jpg)

Need help for getting the value of finish time for both algorithms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the finish time of the First Come First Serve (FCFS) scheduling algorithm, the following formula can be used:

```
Finish Time = Arrival Time + Service Time
```

For calculating the finish time of the Shortest Job First (SJF) scheduling algorithm, the following formula can be used:

```
Finish Time = Maximum(Previous Finish Time, Arrival Time) + Service Time
```

In Visual Basic .NET, the above formulas can be implemented using the following code:

For FCFS:

```
Dim finishTime as Integer
finishTime = arrivalTime + serviceTime
```

For SJF:

```
Dim finishTime as Integer
finishTime = Math.Max(previousFinishTime, arrivalTime) + serviceTime
```

Comment: the arrival time and service time are the textbox for arrival time and burst time right sir?